# How to convert an Array of type Any to a specific type

Tags: julia

Say I have:

```
arr = {"a" "b" "r"}
> 1x3 Array{Any,2}:
> "a"  "b"  "r"
```

and I want it to be of type Array{Symbol,2} say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's also

```
julia> convert(Array{Symbol}, arr)
1x3 Array{Symbol,2}:
:a  :b  :r
```

Comment: This no longer appear to work. See https://discourse.julialang.org/t/correct-use-of-convert/50096 I would suggest a list comprehension: [Symbol(a) for a in arr]

Comment: @born_naked That does not guarantee the correct shape. Broadcasting: `Symbol.(arr)` is better.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
symarr = reshape(Symbol[arr...],size(arr)...)
```

Note also if all the elements in the array are of the type you want, you can use:

```
strarr = reshape([arr...],size(arr)...)
```

If you're happy with a Vector, you can simply use:

```
symvec = Symbol[arr...]
strvec = [arr...]
```

Also here's a macro for fun:

```
macro convarr(a, t)
    :(reshape($t[$a...],size($a)...))
end
@convarr arr Symbol
```

Note that all the above create new copies of the original Array{Any,2} array

Answer (score 0):

Just since this seems to be the top result when I search for this, I will break out my comment into an answer for visibility.

The accepted answer no longer appears to work. [See this link for relevant discussion.](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/correct-use-of-convert/50096)

I would recommend using a list comprehension.

Accepted method

```
arr = ["a" "b" "c"]
1×3 Matrix{String}:
 "a"  "b"  "c"

convert(Array{Symbol}, arr)
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type String to an object of type Symbol
```

Recommended per @DNF comment below.

```
Symbol.(arr)
1×3 Matrix{Symbol}:
 :a  :b  :c
```

Possible solution that may not respect shape.

```
[Symbol(a) for a in arr]
1×3 Matrix{Symbol}:
 :a  :b  :c
```